# ListView alphabetically arrange?

Tags: android, android-listview

How does my listview automatically display data alphabetically. Because in my emulator it display data arrange by how it arranged in my database.

can anyone have a explanation with this issue?

this is how i retrieve data from my database.

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("database", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
          Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT category,cimage from FoodList", null);
          int count = c.getCount();
          String[] values = new String[count];
          String[] values1 = new String[count];
          c.moveToFirst();
          for(int x = 0; x < count; x++){
             values[x] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("category"));
             values1[x] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cimage"));
             c.moveToNext();
          } 


           list.setAdapter(new imageadapter(this,values,values1));
           db.close();
           c.close();
```

here is my imageadapter activity

```
public class imageadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] mobileValues;
    public final String[] mobileValues2;

    public imageadapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues, String[] mobileValues1) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
        this.mobileValues2 = mobileValues1;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        viewHolder holder = new viewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.logo, null);
            holder.category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cat);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imglogo);
             convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.category.setText(mobileValues[position]);
        holder.s = mobileValues2[position];
        byte[] decodedString = null;
        try {
            decodedString = Base64.decode(holder.s, 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
          holder.image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);

        return convertView;
    }




    public int getCount() {
        return mobileValues.length;
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class viewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView category;
        String s;
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean to say, in real device it sorts the elements in alphabetical order and in emulator as per the arrangement in database ?

Comment: yes that's right and I don't want to arrange it alphabetically

Comment: use custom adapter for list. and in adapter sort your list with by what you want.

Comment: please take a look at my edited question

Comment: post your imageAddapter.

Comment: write a method in your imageAdapter and sort your value[] by alphabetically.

Comment: or do @TobiasMoeThorstensen's  answer.

Comment: Do you want to display the list alphabetically according to the category or the cimage?

Comment: no I just want to display it how it arranged on my database.

Comment: what about your database?
Are the data sorted in your database too?

Comment: that's my problem in my device it display the category alphabetically but in emulator its not.

Comment: it my emulator it display how it arranged in my database. but in my device it display the data alphabetically. and I don't know why.

Comment: where should I put the code habib zere?

Comment: check my answer editted.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any query for getting the information from the database? If so, why don't you use a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY your_column
```

Answer (score 1):

get the data from the database by arranging it in the order you are intersted and next add to the arrayadapter.
This may solve your problem

Comment: I retrieve the data from database without any arrangement order. I just used cursor move it to first and the loop it and movetonext. that's all

Comment: then you may have a way to get the data sorted when using rawquery (i think). try it

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor fetchAllData() {
        return database.query(urtablename, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);
    }
```

it will return all data using cursor,In ur activity

```
 Cursor cr=dba.fetchAllData();
    cr.movetofirst();
    while(!cr.isAfterLast())
    {
    //fetch all data using column name
    //like cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("ur column name"));
    //it will return as per in dATABASE
    cr.movetoNext();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom comparator as you need. And now Use this in the sort function of ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

try this in constructor :

```
public imageadapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues, String[] mobileValues1) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
    this.mobileValues2 = mobileValues1;

Arrays.sort(mobileValues);



//Arrays.sort(mobileValues2);

}
```

enjoy.

Comment: in what part of my imageadapter should I add that?

Comment: I see it becomes alphabetically

Comment: the image is scrambled. and that's my problem. I don't want it to display alphabetically.

Comment: the problem is I don't want to display it alphabetically.

Comment: how the data is in your database?

Comment: I just wan't to display it how it arranged in my database

Comment: the arrangement in my database is sort from what I'd input first to last input